# Using Stratified Kfolding (kfold=10) and reaching .99 acc and low loss early on... Is this overfitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

**Question**

When using a stratified k fold approach to cross validation scoring for a pipeline that includes StandardScaler and MLP Sequential Model for binary classfication, can overfitting occur? If it does, it is manageable? Should I continue and train the model if I receive high accuracies after everything is said and done?

**Context**

I designed a classification pipeline that will using MLP/Sequential Models in Keras (and its wrappers for SciKit-Learn) to quickly determine which models were effective enough to train.

Weirdly (or maybe not so weird) I get .99 accuracy and 5.28 x 10^-4 loss after the **first** fold. I know this approach helps combat 'overfitting', but I'm wondering what possible reasons (other than this model works?) could lead to this high accuracy low loss situation after 1 fold.

For reference I attached a display of the entire cross validation process (all folds), and the function below basically just compares the predicted values against the actual values.

[image: Here is an image of the results (I will add code below to show how I make this graph)]

```
def base_model():
    """
    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        model (keras.models.Sequential): Keras based DNN Model
    """

    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(60, input_dim=38, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def display_cross_val_pred(self):
    """This method should display the cross value predictions using matplotlib

    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        None
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(self.Y, self.cross_val_pred, edgecolors=(0, 0, 0))
    ax.plot([self.Y.min(), self.Y.max()], [self.Y.min(), self.Y.max()], 'k--', lw=4)
    ax.set_xlabel('Measured')
    ax.set_ylabel('Predicted')
    plt.show()

def cross_validate(self):
    """
    This will perform a cross validation score using a stratified kfold method. (Think traditional Kfold but
    with the values evenly distributed for each subsample)

    Args:
        None
    Returns:
        None
    """
    self.cross_validation_score = cross_val_score(self.pipeline, self.X, self.Y, cv=self.kfold, verbose=1)
    return self.cross_validation_score

def cross_val_predict(self):
    """This method will return an array same size as self.Y representing predictions for those values

    Args:
        None
    Return
        None
    """
    self.cross_val_pred = cross_val_predict(self.pipeline, self.X, self.Y, cv=self.kfold, verbose=1)
    return self.cross_val_pred
```

**Also, as I'm sure someone will say something. THIS is a class implementation, and rather than copy and paste the ENTIRE code I am only inserting what I feel is relevant. If I am wrong please kindly comment below and refrain from berating me :)**

Comment: no oversampling was done, and data is fairly balanced (I took a stratified approach to ensure it wouldn't screw up sampling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes, it can be overfitted. Your data might be very correlated and easy to predict.

Also, yes, there are ways to manage overfitting of a neural network. Among these you have regularisation (where you suppress coefficients with a penalty) and drop-out (randomly leaving out some neurons during training) and data augmentation (generating more data that looks similar to the actual data). You can obviously also avoid overfitting by getting more data, but I'm guessing you're using all the data available.

As you say "after first fold" I'm assuming that you've trained your network once on the other k-1 parts. In this case you can be "lucky enough" to have a combination of data in the folds making it fit very well to that specific fold. Btw, you could add some  jitter to  your  plot or simply print a confusion matrix to get a better understanding of what's going on.

I'd say the best way to ensure that your model is doing good is to leave out some data to test in the end. Remember to only use a test set once to avoid information leakage.

Comment: Wow great answer. Thank you I will take what you said and try to apply it. Unfortunately I can't upvote this